# is there a way to add custom labels to doxygen output?

Tags: doxygen

If you use doxygen, you'll have noticed how certain adornments can appear in the header bar for the detailed info for a given function. Here's an example, it has the `inline` adornment, another one I've seen is `static` and I expect there are others.

[image: example]

I'm actually using doxygen to document Javascript on a mixed C++/Javascript project and would like to put an `async` adornment into the documentation for functions that are asynchronous. I'm using [Coherent labs](https://coherent-labs.com/documenting-javascript-with-doxygen/) excellent script to do to this.

So, is there a way to insert custom adornments? I'd like the syntax to be something like this:

```
/// @adorn async
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a direct solution in doxygen for "custom" labels. Problem would of course also be that it should work for all output types.
In e.g. LaTeX / PDF the static is shown as `[static]`.

In HTML I think the relevant part is:

`<td class="mlabels-right">
<span class="mlabels"><span class="mlabel">static</span></span>  </td>`

Maybe you could do something with the `css` files / or embedding a javascript script in the HTML code.
Other solution would be to add a command to doxygen that handles this type of requests, but this would mean again a new command in doxygen.

Comment: Setting this as the right answer because, in a roundabout way, it provides it, which is "no". :-)